# Android.. How to Upload data from android phone to remote database?

Tags: android, database

I am doing some android development, and now I need to send some android application

generated data onto a remote server (a database)?

How can I do that? can I use direct JDBC connection and sql?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't come packaged with JDBC.

I recommend that you setup a web service (SOAP, RESTful, etc), and pass/retrieve data that way. It's more secure as well.