# Techiniques for writing Android, iPad, iPhone clients using remote data

Tags: iphone, android, delphi, ipad

I need to explore the world "You wrote a killer application, but do you have an Android/iPhone/iPad client?".

My questions are:

1) which is the best way to send data to those devices? Soap and Rest as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736129/android-how-to-upload-data-from-android-phone-to-remote-database)? Or are there some specific techniques? (My app is written in Delphi and I can expose data with webservices if needed)

2) For x-platform (where by x I mean basically apple prodcuts and android) developement is there a tool? Or the only solution is write one client per platform that "embeds" a web application optimized for mobile devices?

3) which are the techinques for caching locally some data / working offline? Is it different in the 2 worlds or is it common?

Comment: You have three completely separate questions (or possibly even six). Please post each one separately so you can get the best answers for each one.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but somehow i wanted to ask many things "to see what happened". Now I got an interesting link so I will ask explicitly about sencha touch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) 1.0 has been released this week and is free for commercial use now. Sencha Touch 1.0 is compatible with Apple iOS and Google Android.

> Sencha Touch is the world's first app
>   framework built specifically to
>   leverage HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript
>   for the highest level of power,
>   flexibility, and optimization. We make
>   specific use of HTML5 to deliver
>   components like audio and video, as
>   well as a localStorage proxy for
>   saving data offline.

localStorage is a new HTML5 feature which allows to store data on the client. However, it differs from cookies in some key ways. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage

Sencha is the company behind [Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/), the Javascript library which is also available over a Delphi wrapper/binding called [extpascal](http://code.google.com/p/extpascal/), so it is possible that Sencha is based on Ext JS technology, and writing a Delphi client web app could be a logical integration path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link I will ask now explicitly for Sencha touch. Thanks also for local storage info, I didn't know that. Do you know if it is possible to use localStorage as a way to use a web application in total offline mode? So if no internet connection is there is it possible to desing an application so that it will work (using only stored data)?

Comment: "Web storage data is not transmitted to the server in every HTTP request, and a web server can't directly write to Web storage." (from Wikipedia), so yes, it is offline storage, under control of the client side Javascript. For Sencha Touch localStorage, I have not checked the full API documentation but it seems to be the same.

Comment: ok thanks, anyway this is an advanced topic for now. I am stil in the getting started phase. I posted this new question for Delphi and Sencha Touch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209558/delphi-and-sencha-touch.

Answer (score 3):

Only for your number 2, you can check out [GeneXus X Evolution 2](http://www.genexus.com/xev2beta). The main purpose of [GeneXus](http://www.genexus.com/evolution) is to design business applications in a custom IDE, and generate what's needed for each platform you want to target.

The current stable release is the Evolution 1, and targets lots of platforms.

The Evolution 2 is still in development (a beta build is already released, take a look at #XEv2Beta on twitter). When released, It'll add support for the most common smartdevices platforms (Apple, Android, BlackBerry), but later they plan to add support for other platforms too.