# Delphi and Sencha Touch

Tags: delphi, sencha-touch

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206510/techiniques-for-writing-android-ipad-iphone-clients-using-remote-data) I've been told about Sencha Touch as the "solution" fo r writing x-platform mobile/touch application. I browsed [Sencha Touch demos](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/demos.php) using an [iPadSimulator](http://ipadpeek.com/) and wow... The experience is native, not web application.

So for what I need to achieve, this is very good.

Now, how is it possible from Delphi create a Sencha Touch powered application? Did anyone has an example?

ExtPascal doesn't support it directly, I searched on google and I found [this post that states it](http://groups.google.com/group/extpascal/browse_thread/thread/e0928ce2413c776d/38548231bc163a89?q=sencha+touch+extpascal#38548231bc163a89). That post also says it will be supported may be next year.

By the way I also heard that it is possible to use ExtPascal as an engine for the web application (like for having a fast-cgi application) and then simply generate all the javascript manually. So in this case may be it would be possible to use Sencha Touch too.

I am not an expert at all in this area, could you please give me some hint (or some example) to take a good direction?

Thanks.

UPDATE: basically what I mean is, may you please guide me in making the [GeoTweets Demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/getting-started.html) using Delphi, or even better, can anyone post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By studying a little more the subject I "discovered" that Delphi is not needed for creating Sencha Touch applications, since a minimalistic app just needs an html file and a javascript file.

Delphi will come into picture for managing user session and data, but that time the question will not be about Sencha Touch, but probably on how to manage JSON calls with Delphi in the best way. But this after I learnt more about Sencha Touch...